# Mixing svelte components with regular html in a .html file

Tags: svelte

Our backend builds views in .net with episerver CMS, as a frontend developer I would like to provide them with Svelte components which they then add the data for, using props.

Using Vue 2.x we could simply let them use it like this in their .cshtml-files:

```
<div id="main">
  <main class="page">
    <div class="c-page-header">
      <v-main-nav :links='@Html.Raw(Model.Navigation)' />
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Is this possible with svelte components **without** using svelte as web components, this is a show stopper with the lack of not inhereting global CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could emulate a bit of vue syntax yourself:

```js
import MainNav from "MainNav.svelte";

document.querySelectorAll('v-main-nav').forEach((el) => {
  const props = {};
  el.getAttributeNames().forEach((attr) => {
    if (attr[0] === ":") {
      props[attr.substring(1)] = eval(el.getAttribute(attr));
    } else {
      props[attr] = el.getAttribute(attr);
    }
  });
  new MainNav({ target: el, props });
});
```

It doesn't work with nested components (<slot /> inside MainNav doesn't work) and you might want to add `style="display: contents"` to the `v-main-nav` element as the svelte component will be mounted inside that dom element.